# Grammatically Correct? {Verb} {Plural Noun} For {Productive Noun}

Tags: zero-article

> **Sentence #1** Why do game engines use gimbals for rotation?

[image]

> **Sentence #2** Don't use gimbals for rotation.

Grammarly says the 1st sentence is wrong, but no correction pops up on the 2nd sentence. Is the following form grammatically correct?

> ... {Verb} {Plural Noun} For {Productive Noun} ...

Comment: Is which grammar incorrect?  You're displaying three different sentences, and it's not clear which you mean.

Comment: @Andrew How are these 3 different sentences?

Comment: It's not clear what you intend with the Grammarly screenshot.   It makes no sense to me.  I recommend you delete it and just write out, clearly, what you want to know.

Comment: @Andrew What I want to know is if Grammarly is right or wrong.

Comment: "Grammarly says the 1st example is wrong"  I have no idea which is the "1st example" since the image is a clutter of multiple examples.  Do you mean one of the sentences in the image?  Or the sentence in the title?  Or the first sentence in the blockquote?  Just be clear and concise, so it's easy to understand, and I'm happy to help out.

Comment: @The 1st example is the 1st blockquote. The 2nd example is the 2nd blockquote.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with, "Why do game engines use gimbals for rotation?".  "Don't use gimbals for rotation" is similarly fine.  If Grammarly marks them wrong, then it's a false negative.

Comment: What's the correlation between the lack of an article in front of *rotation* and *{Verb} {Plural Noun} For {Productive Noun}*?

Comment: @JasonBassford -- My guess is that *{Verb} {Plural Noun} for {Productive Noun}* is the original poster's abstraction of "Sentence #2".  The original poster assumed that the grammar checker was correct, and was wondering why sentence #2 was correct if the similar sentence #1 was incorrect.

Comment: Consider the trash can and "IGNORE". It is making recommendations but it is your job to determine if they are valid or not. Your question should include some additional research. Just asking whether "Grammarly" is right or wrong is more of a software reliability question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are correct.  Neither sentence needs an article before "rotation", because each sentence is talking about the concept of "rotation", not any particular "rotation".

If either sentence were talking about a particular rotation that had already been referred to, it would need a definite article ("the") (or another determiner).  If it were introducing a particular rotation, it would need an indefinite article ("a") (or another determiner).